# Quartz Cron job fails to trigger properly in Kubernetes Environment

Tags: java, kubernetes, cron, quartz-scheduler

We have 4 cron jobs of Quartz each triggering at

```
0 */5 * ? * * - 5 mins
0 0 */1 ? * * - 1 hr 
0 */1 * ? * * - 1 min
0 */3 * ? * * - 3 mins
```

All the jobs works fine in local and single cluster environment.
but when we switch to more than one pod the job with 3 mins trigger starts to misbehave and goes on to trigger at every 2 hour or randomly.

We are using Springboot and Quartz scheduler and standard Kubernetes Helm chart deployment in our production.

Cron triggers are defined in the application.properties. any reason or pointers to make it consistent would be great